# How do I enable agent for mib-2 using pysnmp?

Tags: pysnmp

I just installed **pysnmp** on my linux machine using **pip install pysnm**p.  What do I need to do, in order to have an agent running for **mib-2**?  I want to be able to **get** the **sysDescr.0** object.  Right now, I get a "No Response" as below, because there is no agent that services mib-2.  Do I need to write my own agent for this?  Or, if pysnmp provides an agent for this standard mib, how do I run it?

```
snmpget -v2c -c public 10.11.73.109 1.2.6.1.2.1.1.0
```

> Timeout: No Response from 10.11.73.109

Comment: You need to write your own agent because pysnmp is a library. You may get some inspiration from the example scripts.

Comment: Thanks @IlyaEtingof